# Is a pyramid uniquely determined by its edge-lengths?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry, metric-geometry

I am looking for a nice/short proof of the following:

> The shape of a pyramid with a convex polygonal base is already uniquely determined by knowing the length of all its edges.

By "knowing the length of each edge", I mean that I know the edge-graph of the pyramid, and to each edge of the graph I know its length. So we *cannot* freely permute the lengths among the edges.

Also, I consider mirror images as the same "shape".

---

**Proof of a special case**

Suppose that the perpendicular projection of the apex onto the (affine hull of the) base ends up *inside* the base (in its relative interior).

In that case, we can mirror the pyramid on its base to obtain the corresponding double-pyramid, which again is a convex polyhedron.

[image]

All the faces of the double-pyramid are triangles, and so their shapes are uniquely determined by the edge lengths (which we know). Then the whole double-pyramid is uniquely determined by [Cauchy's rigidity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(geometry)), which then uniquely determined the original pyramid as well.

Apparently, this no longer works if the projection of the apex is outside of the base (or on its boundary), as the mirroring trick no longer gives a convex polyhedron, or might give a polyhedron with non-triangular faces.

---

**Discussing degrees of freedom**

We can assume that the vertices of the base are contained in a fixed plane, and that only the apex is hovering above the plane.
This gives the configuration $2n+3$ degrees of freedom.

Now, we also have $2n$ length constraint.
The remaining three degrees of freedom are exactly translation parallel to the plane (two degrees of freedom), and rotation around an axes spanned by the normal vector of the plane (one degree of freedom).

So the configuration has no degrees of freedom to deform continuously, *but* this does not exclude the case of multiple rigid configurations with the same given edge-lengths.

Comment: Are we to assume that the order of the edge lengths of the polygonal base is fixed and known?  If not, the claim is false because we can inscribe an $n$-gon in a circle and permute the edges in such a way that the pyramids formed by any apex situated on the perpendicular axis through the incenter will have the same edge lengths, but they the pyramids are not congruent.

Comment: @heropup Basically we are given the combinatorial type of the pyramid (aka. its edge-graph), and for each edge in this type we know its length. And I ask about the realization space of that type. So the "order of the edges" is meant to be fixed.

Comment: Your pyramid might exist in two different shapes which are the mirror images of each other; does that count?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I want to consider mirror images the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a counterexample in the case when the apex is not "above" the base face:

[image]

Here are two non-congruent polygons with pair-wise identical edge-lengths and pair-wise identical vertex-distances to the white dot.
You can imagine to raise the white dot out of the plane do create two non-congruent pyramids with identical edge lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple counterexample: The base is a many-sided polygon inscribed in a circle and the lengths of sides are distinct; the apex is a point not in that plane. ("Many"${}={}$at least four.)

Now interchange two adjacent edges of the base to get a different shape.

Comment: *"By 'knowing the length of each edge', I mean that I know the edge-graph of the pyramid, and to each edge of the graph I know its length. So we **cannot** freely permute the lengths among the edges."*

Comment: @Blue : What about the edges that go from a vertex of the base up to the apex. If those are not specified, then we can freely move the apex within a plane parallel to the base without changing the volume.

Comment: *All* the edge-lengths (and the arrangement thereof) are specified. Also, the question isn't about preserving *volume* but *shape*.

Comment: @Blue : Those motions of the apex within that plane change the shape.

Comment: *"Those motions of the apex within that plane change the shape."* They also (typically) change the lengths of edges joining the apex to the base vertices, so they're outside the realm of consideration for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If the edge graph of the pyramid with polygonal base indeed would be fully specified (e.g. by means of a map which length is addressed to which edge), then so are all its lacing triangles as such as well as their sequencing in their cycle around the apex. Then, if n>3 for the base polygon, you only have the freedom of dimpling in or out vertices of the base in such a way that its lacing edge still keeps the same length (and the base keeps flat). However, your further requirement about a convex base disallows that too.

--- rk

Comment: A counterexample was already giving in a different answer. So your argument must be incomplete.

Comment: Agreed. At least my argument indeed is correct in that the lacing triangles are rigid, i.e. the base vertices only can dimple in or out. These correspond to the two circle intersection points of your construction. However, some strange correlation between pairs of neighbouring base vertices, simultanuously dimpling into the other position, could take place, even in such a way, which keeps the outcome still convex...